# Loading image from URL with thread and how to cancel the thread on dealloc

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uitableview

Guys, could you help me with a good example or a lead where I should start or a right google keyword for this operation.

I want to start to learn about threading in iPhone but I don’t know how to start because I don’t know the right term or keyword to search for.

If you have an example for this example is the best..

Steps :

1. I want to load a lot of images. let say 1000 images
2. The image will be loaded to a table view in CustomTableCell.
3. For each CustomTableCell that visible (let say I will shown only 10 image) I will create a separate thread to load each of the image from an URL so there will be 10 thread.
4. If the image is successfully downloaded, I will cache the image (the cache is let say 100 image max),(note: on step 3, I actually will check if the image is available in cache first before download the image from URL).
5. But, if the user scroll the table and some of the CustomTableCell now is not visible, and I need to cancel/stop the thread and allocate the thread to new visible CustomTableCell.

The parts that I am confused :

1. about is how to create and stop the thread,
2. how do i know if the cell is not visible anymore,is it on cellForRowAtIndexPath?, if it dequed by the table view the thread is running isn't ?.
3. Basicly i don't know how to implement the threading in TableViewCellController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the SDWebImage class library. It I used it for my project and it's pretty solid. I think it can help with what you're looking for.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: No problem, I love that library :)